# In plug-in.xml how to associate a file extension with a particular kind of editor in eclipse plug-in

Tags: eclipse, file, plugins, editor

I'm developing an eclipse plug-in in which when files with extension  ".cert" are to be associated with a certain kind of editor whose implementation is in RateBuilderEditor.java ?
I think, I have to mention this in plugin.xml ? How do I achieve this ? How to write this ExtensionPoint ?

Answer (score 3):

Here you go:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.editors">
  <editor
    class="[editor-impl-class]"
    default="true"
    filenames="*.cert"
    id="[some-id-or-use-impl-class]"
    name="My Custom Editor"
    icon="images/something.png"/>
</extension>
```