# Associate eclipse plug-in view with a file extension

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, file-association

I'm developing an eclipse plug-in and I would like to open files with a certain **extension** (e.g. .xml) with the **View** tab of my plug-in. Is this possible? I know this can be done for editors like this [In plug-in.xml how to associate a file extension with a particular kind of editor in eclipse plug-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317563/in-plug-in-xml-how-to-associate-a-file-extension-with-a-particular-kind-of-edito).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between a View and an Editor has **diminished** with Eclipse 4. This means that you can **dock editors outside the shared area** on a view stack. Go ahead and try it by dragging an Editor by its title and dropping it on a view stack.

Furthermore, **it is very well possible to edit files in views** if you want to implement this yourself. For this to happen you have to implement ***ISaveablePart*** [1] on the view. When you implement this, the view will play in the change/dirty/save editor lifecycle of the workbench.

[1] http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fui%2FISaveablePart.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems to be the only way. Do you have any example of usage? I couldn't find much on the web.

Comment: This is all very good with ISaveablePart as far as saving is concerned. But what about opening the file that has been saved? How can I open it in the view?

Comment: You have to create a command or action that opens your view with the filename as parameter. Standard Eclipse IDE will open an editor when double clicking but you can create your own actions that will open the file in a view.  You have to do the loading etc.. yourself.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible.

The closest you can get is to add a separate 'open in view' menu item.

Comment: In Eclipse, editors should be used to show or edit files. See also https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_What_is_the_difference_between_a_view_and_an_editor%3F